# When search on column have numbers and character not search for text?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, devexpress

I work with an ASP.NET DevExpress v19 grid view. I face an issue when searching in the grid view column "Depart code".

It accepts a filter and searches by numbers, but text does not accept filter.

As an example, column "Depart Code" has a value of `101HRE`.

- If I search for `101`, I get a result value of `101HRE` successfully.
- If I search for `HRE`, I do not get a result - an empty result set is returned

Why does it accept search by numbers and not accept search by text on column "Depart Code"?

Full code details

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SickLeaveDashboard.aspx.cs" Inherits="UCHRADMIN.SickLeaveDashboard" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.v19.1, Version=19.1.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" Namespace="DevExpress.Web" TagPrefix="dx" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

                    <dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" Width="100%" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SettingsExport-FileName="Leave Type DashBoard" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" KeyFieldName="ID" ClientInstanceName="grid"  Theme="PlasticBlue" >
                        <SettingsPager PageSize="10">
                        </SettingsPager>

                        <SettingsExport EnableClientSideExportAPI="true"/>
                        <SettingsEditing EditFormColumnCount="1" Mode="PopupEditForm">
                        </SettingsEditing>
                        <Settings ShowFilterRow="True"  ShowGroupPanel="True" />
                        <SettingsPopup>
                            <EditForm Modal="True" ShowShadow="True" VerticalAlign="WindowCenter" HorizontalAlign="WindowCenter">
                            </EditForm>
                        </SettingsPopup>
                          <Toolbars>
            <dx:GridViewToolbar>
                <SettingsAdaptivity Enabled="True" EnableCollapseRootItemsToIcons="True" />
                <Items>
                    <dx:GridViewToolbarItem Command="ExportToXls" />
                </Items>
            </dx:GridViewToolbar>
        </Toolbars>
                        <Columns>

                            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Emp No" Visible="True" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="1">
                                <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
                            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Emp Name"  VisibleIndex="2" PropertiesTextEdit-ValidationSettings-RequiredField-IsRequired="true">
                            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                             <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn  FieldName="Dept Code" VisibleIndex="3" PropertiesTextEdit-ValidationSettings-RequiredField-IsRequired="true">
                            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Dept Name" VisibleIndex="4" PropertiesTextEdit-ValidationSettings-RequiredField-IsRequired="true">
                            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                             <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="With Attachment" VisibleIndex="5" PropertiesTextEdit-ValidationSettings-RequiredField-IsRequired="true">
                            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                             <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Without Attachment"  VisibleIndex="6" PropertiesTextEdit-ValidationSettings-RequiredField-IsRequired="true">
                            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>



                             <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Year"  VisibleIndex="7" PropertiesTextEdit-ValidationSettings-RequiredField-IsRequired="true">
                            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

                        </Columns>
                    </dx:ASPxGridView>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
                        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
                        SelectCommand="SELECT
    r.EmpNo AS [Emp No],
    EmpName AS [Emp Name],
    cast(REPLACE(REPLACE(m.DEPT, ' ', ''), CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), '')  as varchar(100)) AS [Dept Code],
    cast(b.MCDL01  as nvarchar(200)) AS [Dept Name],
    SUM(CASE WHEN (r.AttachmentFileName IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [With Attachment],
    SUM(CASE WHEN (r.AttachmentFileName = '' or r.AttachmentFileName IS NULL ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Without Attachment],
    YEAR(r.FromDate) AS [Year]
    into #y
FROM
    [dbo].[tblRequest] r
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[vEmployeeMaster] m ON m.EMPNO = r.EmpNo
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[vBusinessUnitMaster] b ON MCMCU = m.DEPT
WHERE
    r.RequestType IN ('SLP', 'SLH', 'SLU') --and m.DEPT like '%101%'
GROUP BY
    r.EmpNo, EmpName, m.DEPT, YEAR(r.FromDate), b.MCDL01
ORDER BY r.EmpNo, EmpName

select * from #y" >

                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

This screenshot shows the issue:

[image: column not filter]

Comment: but this comment on sql so how it applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching for %HRE.

I haven't use the aspx version of DevExpress, but I would suspect it would behave similar to the Winforms version where HRE is translated in a filter of **Starts with**
and %HRE is translated into a **Contains**

Answer (score 0):

This SelectCommand appears to incorrect.    "--and"

```
WHERE
        r.RequestType IN ('SLP', 'SLH', 'SLU') --and m.DEPT like '%101%'
```

Comment: but this comment on sql so how it applied (and m.DEPT like '%101%') commented

Comment: I guess so, I have experienced the similar issue just because of the comment.

Comment: when apply statement on sql server with comment it will not apply --and m.DEPT like '%101%' because it comment so what other solution i can try

Comment: I understood. Well, I do suggest to remove this comment first in case that it somehow caused some unexpected issue. Then let's see what happens.

Comment: i remove comment sql statment  --and m.DEPT like '%101%' it but nothing changes and issue still exist

Comment: SqlDataSource.FilterExpression Property may be helpful. Back to you soon.